# Querying internal metadata server from React app hosted on Google Cloud Run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm implementing Google Cloud's [service-to-service authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) between two apps hosted on Cloud Run. A client-side React app - created using create-react-app - will be making calls to a server-side Node.js app, where the latter doesn't have unauthenticated invocation allowed.

However, I'm not able to query the internal metadata server form my React app to get an authorization token. When running the request in the sample code on that page, I get the error in the attached screenshot. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Code to make call:

```
const buttonClickHandler = async (event) => {
   const metadataServerTokenURL = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
   const tokenRequestOptions = {
       uri: metadataServerTokenURL + process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,
       headers: {
          'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
       }
   };

   // Fetch the token, then provide the token in the request to the receiving service
   request(tokenRequestOptions)
     .then((token) => {
       return request(process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL).auth(null, null, true, token)
     })
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
     });
}
```

Error:
`TypeError: Failed to fetch`

[Browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C8XF.png)

Answer (score 0):

This service-to-service procedure you linked in your question is, as mentioned in the name, for service to service communication.

The documentation you shared mentions this:

> Note that this method does not work outside of Google Cloud, including from your local machine.

The metadata server is not intended to be called from outside Google Cloud. This is why it is not working in your browser.

If you are calling a backend container, you could:

- make this backend container callable by unauthenticated users (IAM role: "roles/run.invoker", member: "allUsers")
- Implement token retrieval with `firebase/auth` and the Identity Platform.