# Correctly fetch authentication tokens server-side in a node.js React app hosted on Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client

While not a front-end developer, I'm trying to set up a web app to show up a demo for a product. That app is based on the [Sigma.js demo app demo repository](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/cb61ba3835862e9998accbbeac54b9834ae21ffd/demo).

You'll notice that this app relies on a graph which is hosted locally, which is loaded as:

**/src/views/Root.tsx** :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/dataset.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((dataset: Dataset) => {...
                       // do things ....
```

and I wish to replace this by a call to another service which I also host on Cloud Run.

My first guess was to use the gcloud-auth-library, but I could not make it work - especially since it does not seem to support Webpack > 5 (I might be wrong here), the point here this lib introduces many problems in the app, and I thought I'd be better off trying the other way GCP suggests to handle auth tokens: by calling the Metadata server.

So I replaced the code above with:

**Root.tsx** :

```
import { getData } from "../getGraphData";

 useEffect(() => {
    getData()
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((dataset: Dataset) => {
      // do even more things!
```

**getGraphData.js** :

```
import { getToken } from "./tokens";

const graphProviderUrl = '<my graph provider service URL>';

export const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await getToken();
    console.log(
      "getGraphData.js :: getData : received token",
      token
    );
    const request = await fetch(
      `${graphProviderUrl}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const data = await request.json();
    console.log("getGraphData.js :: getData : received graph", data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("getGraphData.js :: getData : error getting graph data", error);
    return error.message;
  }
};
```

**tokens.js** :

```
const targetAudience = '<my graph provider service base URL>'; // base URL as audience
const metadataServerAddress = "169.254.169.254"; // use this to shortcut DNS call to metadata.google.internal

export const getToken = async () => {
    if (tokenExpired()) {
      const token = await getValidTokenFromServer();
      sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", token.accessToken);
      sessionStorage.setItem("expirationDate", newExpirationDate());
      return token.accessToken;
    } else {
      console.log("tokens.js 11 | token not expired");
      return sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    }
  };
  
  const newExpirationDate = () => {
    var expiration = new Date();
    expiration.setHours(expiration.getHours() + 1);
    return expiration;
  };
  
  const tokenExpired = () => {
    const now = Date.now();
  
    const expirationDate = sessionStorage.getItem("expirationDate");
    const expDate = new Date(expirationDate);
  
    if (now > expDate.getTime()) {
      return true; // token expired
    }
  
    return false; // valid token
  };
  
  const getValidTokenFromServer = async () => {
    // get new token from server
    try {
      const request = await fetch(`http://${metadataServerAddress}/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?audience=${targetAudience}`, {
        headers: {
            'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'
        }
      });
      const token = await request.json();
      return token;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error("Issue getting new token", error.message);
    }
  };
```

I know that this kind of call will need to be done server-side. What I don't know is how to have it happen on a React + Node app. I've tried my best to integrate good practices but most questions related to this topic (request credentials through a HTTP (not HTTPS!) API call) end with answers that just say "you need to do this server-side", without providing more insight into the implementation.

There is a question with similar formulation and setting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67653993/querying-internal-metadata-server-from-react-app-hosted-on-google-cloud-run) but the single answer, no upvote and comments is a bit underwhelming. If the actual answer to the question is *"you cannot ever call the metadata server from a react app and need to set up a third-party service to do so (e.g. firebase)"*, I'd be keen on having it said explicitly!

Please assume I have only a very superficial understanding of node.js and React!